# Can't connect to SQL db from C# webform

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I've tried several different connection strings and always get the same error: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 22.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Web; using System.Web.UI; using System.Web.UI.WebControls; using System.Data.Sql; using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1 { public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page { protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Brandon-PC\brandon;Initial Catalog=STATUS;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
    connection.Open();

    string clientname = TextBox1.Text;
    string sqlquery = ("INSERT INTO [STATUS] (Client_Name) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Client_Name", clientname);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked you are using the correct connection string values?    http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote backslash, either:

```
SqlConnection connection = 
   new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Brandon-PC\brandon;Initial Catalog=STATUS;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
```

or

```
SqlConnection connection = 
   new SqlConnection("Data Source=Brandon-PC\\brandon;Initial Catalog=STATUS;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
```

Plus, your code should be:

```
string clientname = TextBox1.Text; 
string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO [STATUS] (Client_Name) VALUES (@Client_Name)"; 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_Name", clientname); 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[Note: I'm assuming undescores are ok in the query text parameters; I never use them.]

[Also note: you do not need `integrated security=SSPI` AND `Trusted_Connection=Yes`. They are synonyms; one is sufficient.]

Comment: Thanks...but now its saying that the db, STATUS, is not a valid object. The exception is thrown at the very last line. I've initialized a connection to this db with VS, so it definitely exists.

Comment: Yes, I do. As I said, I'm able to connect to it just fine using VS. STATUS is an acronym..Service Time and Tracking Update System. It's a ticket tracker for work.

Comment: "Invalid object name 'STATUS'" and its pointing at the very last semi colon

Comment: Haven't gotten it to work, but you solved the first problem. Thanks.